# How to filter right data which changed by ajax in jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I have build table with jquery-datatable. My datatable's config is:

```
$('#example1').DataTable(tableOption){
    order:[[1, 'desc']],
    //....
    searching: true,  //use default search function
    //....
}
```

When data loaded, there is an ajax request which to change one row's data, such as:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'...',
    //....
    sucess:function(data){
        var newStatusStr= 'Retrieved';  //before was : Published
        tr.find('.schedule_status').html(newStatusStr);
        tr.find('.schedule_status').attr('title', newStatusStr);        
    }
})
```

After ajax complete, the td data has changed (from "Published" to "Retrieved"), but when I input "Published", datatable's search result was still with old data. 
Here are some screenshots:

1. [Image of initial search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVEIP.png)
2. [Image that changed by ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/199k9.png)
3. [Image of html element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr6o3.png)

You can see that by compare image 1 and image 2

I've looked up a lot of documents about datatable, but still have no idea, How can i do to get the right result?
Thanks very much!

Comment: You need to use the DataTables API if you want to manipulate table content.  Using jQuery does basically just change the visible presence on screen, not the underlying data or content itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you're updating the UI only. You need to instead update the data which DataTables is using to render the table. To do that use [`cell().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()).

In your case it would look something like this:

```
success: function(data) {
  var newStatusStr = 'Retrieved';
  var $td = tr.find('.schedule_status').attr('title', newStatusStr);
  var cell = table.cell($td[0]);
  cell.data(newStatusStr).draw();      
}
```

Note that in the example above `table` is a reference to your DataTable instance. Also note that you don't appear to have defined `retrieveStr` anywhere. I'm presuming that should be `newStatusStr` instead.